# AngularJS multiple routes with same template shouldn't rerender

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes, rerender

I have several views that use the same template, only the number of route params is different, how can I set it up so that the view doesn't get rerendered every time the route changes, tried with `reloadOnSearch: false`, but it didn't work for some reason.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/feeds', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/feeds.html',
            controller: 'FeedsController'
        })
        .when('/feeds/:country', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/feeds.html',
            controller: 'FeedsController'
        })
        .when('/feeds/:country/:competition', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/feeds.html',
            controller: 'FeedsController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/feeds'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), You cannot define multiple `path's` for one route. So in your case you should define two unique `routes` like:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/feeds/:country/:competition/:event', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/event.html',
        controller: 'EventController'
    })
    .when('/feeds/:country/:competition', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/feeds.html',
        controller: 'FeedsController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/feeds'
    });
}]);
```

Difference, always call this URL with full params like:

> http://yourapplication/feeds/false/false/false
>
> http://yourapplication/feeds/1/false/false
>
> http://yourapplication/feeds/1/2/false
>
> http://yourapplication/feeds/1/2/3

And the one who is calling `FeedsController` is still unique with only two params:

> http://yourapplication/feeds/1/2/

Comment: I can't use urls like: http://myapplication/feeds/false/false/false, the user has to be able to enter any of the following urls: http://myapplication/feeds/1, http://myapplication/feeds/1/2 or http://myapplication/feeds/1/2/3 without entering "false"